# arc4random_uniform() causes warning in Xcode 5 but not Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my iOS application, I am writing a function to get a random `NSString` with some specified number of characters from the alphanumeric alphabet. Here is my code:

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

- (NSString *)randomStringWithLength:(int)len {
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform([letters length]) % [letters length]]];
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

Now the function should cause a warning about `arc4random_uniform` since `[letters length]` returns an `unsigned long`, and `arc4random_uniform` expects an `unsigned int`.

In Xcode 5, this warning appears. However, in Xcode 6, there is no warning.

Comment: Are your compiler warning options the same in both versions?

Comment: Are you sure that you have selected the same build target on both platforms, i.e. you are not looking at a 32-bit vs. 64-bit difference?

Comment: @0O0O0O0 exactly the same.

Comment: I tested both on 64 bit, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> The function should return a warning only if there's no clear implicit
>   cast.

The full list of implicit warnings that the compiler "should" warn about, assuming you stuck with the default options, are:

[image]

I added the following to a project:

```
arc4random_uniform([@[] count]);
```

I received the warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision:...". Which will be the implicit conversion to [a] 32-bit type. The C standard does not mandate a warning.

[image]

I'm willing to bet that your project has non-default selections for those warnings.